# Would I get charged for clients' Cloud Storage JSON API calls?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I built a package in R which basically wraps around the [Cloud Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/). I included a default OAuth app (that is a client id and client secret, see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#installed)) in the package. The client id and secret are created and hosted in my own cloud platform project with my billing details. The R package uses the OAuth app to ask for end user's authentication before any API calls and stores the token for the end user. Any subsequent API calls are sent with the retrieved token.

I noticed that the stats about the end users' API calls are showing up in my own project because it hosts the OAuth app. In this case, do I get charged for those API calls by end users?

Comment: You should _not_ publish your billable client secret.

Answer (score 0):

All calls to GCS are always billed to the bucket that they reference. Calls  that don't specify a specific bucket, like "list buckets in a project", are billed to the project in question.

Comment: Thanks, Brandon! Is this documented anywhere in GCP websites?

Answer (score 0):

Your JAVA JavaScript Structructured Omitts Notations are very local and require a great deal with NAMESPACE as it will resolve quite rampantly if not given a proper address pool I suggest Googles DNS alongside subsequent calls within the given IP zone 10.10.10.10/12 etc ... As higher languages like human language tend to fall outside these zone and need to be delegated ... Might be jumping from 0.0.0.0 to higher address pools without knowing can be a pain.